# How to determine return type, arguments, function name from C99 function declarations

Tags: c, perl, c99

I'm looking for the simpliest way, how to determine return type, arguments and function name from c header file written under C99.

it's my school project, which have to be written in Perl without any libs. So i got a few options, i can use the regular expression, but it's not applicable to the hardest function like folowing:

```
int * (* func(int * arg[]))();
```

the return type should be "**int * (* )()**" and argument is "**int * []**".

Second way is to use grammar and parse it, but i think, that this is not the right way.

My buddy told me about an existing algorithm which can do it. But he doesn't remember name, or where he saw him. The algorithm was quite simple. Something like: Find first end parenthesis, everything between this end parenthesis and the first-match previous start parenthesis is arguments...

Does anyone have some idea what am I looking for?

Comment: You mean this? http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html

Comment: This is a parsing problem. Why do you feel that *parsing* is not the right approach?

Comment: @JonPrudy: Basic part of this header parser can be written by regular expressions to get 10/10 points. The advanced part can be awarded by 1 bonus point. So I think I do not have to write complicated parser to get 1 bonus point. But I could be wrong :D

**Cong Xu** thanks for algorithm I was looking for, but as I can see, it's not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [magic decoder ring for C declarations](http://books.google.com/books?id=4vm2xK3yn34C&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=magic%20decoder%20ring%20for%20C%20declarations&source=bl&ots=Ho92Ui-J9T&sig=fsl-7Hs4-rfM91r9DhH-LEuxgCE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LMomUfjAG-TB2wX1zYHgCQ&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=magic%20decoder%20ring%20for%20C%20declarations&f=false)

Comment: I am looking for simple algorithm without knowledge of BNF or other grammar rules, so this seems to be right way. For now, thanks.

Comment: @l0v3, if this is the "right answer" be sure and select it.  Thanks!

Comment: excuse me, I'm such a newbie here, so I'll try the solution before mark it as the right :)

Comment: @l0v3, sure, but Peter Van Der Linden will haunt your dreams if you are questioning his tome.  BTW, if you are C newbie and want to become an expert, I HIGHLY recommend this book, it will change your life.

Answer (score 2):

If you can obtain [*The C Programming Language*](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.4437&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Kernighan and Ritchie.  Not only is it the C bible, but in chapter 5 they present code to parse C declarations.  You can look there to see how they do it and quite possibly adapt their approach (chapter 5, section 12).

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to build a [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) for that kind of problem. Usually the top-down approach (e.g. a [recursive descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)) would do it for this kind of job. Fortunately top-down parsers are more or less straight forward to implement.

The only hard bit in C like languages is, that these languages are usually at least LL1 (1 token look ahead) or even worse LL2 or more. So sometimes you have to peek a few tokens in advance to find out whether it's a function declaration or a function call for example.